# Using Content Management Systems for Clients

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

I am a web developer. Now my problem is that many of my clients want to update their web pages themselves, but I do not want to let them edit my html/css/javascript raw code, and even teaching them is already to much trouble. So I guess is to probably use a CMS (against my liking of course, cause I like doing the coding from scratch).

Now is this the only route to go (CMSs) and what CMS is the best to use? From what I see, Wordpress is the most popular, and most flexible/user friendly

What do you suggest?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want this article http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-evaluate-what-cms-to-use/ They have a very good explanation as to what CMS will fit for you.

Comment: Thank you. Insightful. What would you personally recommend?

Comment: Of course I would go to wordpress. Its easy to use and I just love it. :) By the way Ive tried joomla and drupal too but I would still stick to WP. Thank you for accepting my answer. :)